# Laplace transform does not work

Tags: laplace-transform, wolfram-alpha

I tried to use Laplace transform for this expression using Wolfram Alpha : $3.297\times10^9s^{-2.327}+1480$, but even Wolfram cannot do this... Why ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Is it $3.297\times10^9s^{-2.327}+1480$

Comment: Yes it is this expression that I don't achieve to calculate in the laplace domain

Comment: Try with `InverseLaplaceTransform[3.297e+09*s^(-2.327)+1480,s,t]` in http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Answer (score 1):

The Laplace transform of $a s^b + c$ is given by
$$
\mathcal{L}_{s \to t}[a s^b + c] = \frac{c}{t} + \frac{a \Gamma(b+1)}{t^{b+1}}
$$
where $\Gamma(x)$ is the gamma function, which is a continuous version of the factorial function. You can see by [this link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LaplaceTransform%5Ba%20s%5Eb%20%2B%20c,s,t%5D) that it thinks this is only valid for $\Re(b)>-1$ which your expression doesn't follow. So this might be the reason why it couldn't return an answer.